# Why is sscanf skipping the first 4 characters in each string?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to phrase a file. Each line has a tag and a value. I want to look for a specific tag and then return the associated value.

I am using sscanf to read the tag and value into two variables that I analyses. However sscanf is skipping the first for characters in the string I send it.

```
sscanf(line.c_str(), "%s%d", &tag, &value);
```

For example, if the string is "NumPoints 5" then tag gets "oints". It is consistently skipping the first four characters. I have checked, getline is getting the full line, something is going wrong at the sscanf part.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
int readNumberOfWaypointsInFile(char* filename)
{
    int num_waypoints = 0;

    std::fstream file;
    file.open(filename, std::ios::in);

    std::string line;

    std::string tag;
    int value;

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (getline (file, line))
        {
            sscanf(line.c_str(), "%s%d", &tag, &value);

            if(tag == "NumPoints")
            {
                num_waypoints = value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    file.close();

    return num_waypoints;
}
```

Comment: Which implementation of `getline` are you using?

Comment: @Qix: this one: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/ but that's not the problem.

Comment: You could simply use `while (file >> tag >> value)`, or if you want stronger checking that two such values appear on each line (rather than potentially broken across lines), then inside your current `while (getline(file,line)) {` add `std::istringstream iss(line); and if (iss >> tag >> value) { ... use tag/value... } else { std::cerr << "line '" << line << "' didn't contain a tag and value\n"; exit(1); }`  BTW you can collapse your file-handling code to `if (std::ifstream file(filename)) { while... } else std::cerr << "unable to open file\n";` and let the destructor do the `close`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable warnings in your compiler, and pay attention to them (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror`).  This would have told you your problem: you are passing the address of a C++ string to the C function `sscanf()` which expects a C-style string (char array).  This is undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm confused by this, std::string::c_str() returns a null terminated char array doesn't it? This is how I've seen it used in every example I can remember, including all the ones I checked before posting here to see what was wrong.

Comment: @Francis: the problem is `&tag`, not `line.c_str()`.  You're passing the address of `tag` which is a C++ string.  You can't do that, because `sscanf()` doesn't understand C++ strings.

Comment: Ah, right I misunderstood that, that makes perfect sense now.